# Gitolite fine-grained branch access on Bitbucket Server

Tags: git, gitolite, bitbucket-server

I would like to institute branch-specific access to a number of repositories hosted by a Bitbucket server instance. The problem is that Bitbucket only lets you put in branch-specific restrictions on a repository level.

This becomes very inconvenient when trying to administrate 15+ repositories that all have the same or similar branching schemes. Our current solution is to have home grown pre-receive hooks that do the checking. However, after having used Gitolite in a previous iteration of our workflow I recognize that it would be even safer and convenient if I could administrate my branches using Gitolite's repo groups.

Can anyone come up with a solution that does not involve too much of a hack, that will allow me to connect my BitBucket hook to Gitolite in such a way that users and groups, and authentication will be via Bitucket server.

Answer (score 0):

**[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html)** is supposed to sit between your listener (ssh or https) and the git repos themselves, no matter what the server is.

The problem is that [BitBucket server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/administering-bitbucket-server-776640044.html) might plug itself already in its own http server, or [own sshd server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/enabling-ssh-access-to-git-repositories-in-bitbucket-server-776640358.html).

So you might have to setup an intermediate listener which will use gitolite and, if that passes, would push to your actual BitBucket server (checking if that push succeeds, or returning the error message if not)